# Simple Encryption/Decryption in QtWebkit

Tags: html, qt, encryption, qtwebkit, qwebview

I’m making a browser using QWebView and I want to achieve the following things:

Browser——->sends request to server——->server responds with encrypted html——->browser decrypts the html and shows it.

But the problem is I cannot figure out how to decrypt the received html before viewing it.
I haven’t found any signals or virtual functions that I could override.

I even tried changing the QNetworkAccessManager and then tried tampering with the QNetworkReply, but the QNetworkReply is readonly.

So has anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: What is wrong with just using a HTTPS URL and letting it do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Make the request over HTTPS and let SSL handle all the encryption for you.

Comment: Isn't there any other solution than SSL? What I'm asking seems to be very simple, there has to be some way.

Comment: Decent encryption is **not** simple. This is why we do not reinvent the wheel and, instead, use a robust, well tested, well supported system which has libraries with very simple APIs.

Comment: Ok, but what if want to change the data completely, or I want to append additional html to it? What I'm saying is, I want to tamper with the received html data. Isn't there any way to do it?

Comment: You can tamper with it before it has been encrypted by the server. You can tamper with it once it has been decrypted by the client. You can't tamper with it while it is encrypted (which is the point of encryption).

Comment: Yes I know, so I want to tamper with the html data after it has been decrpyted by the client. So how do I do it?

Comment: The same way that you would if you were getting plain HTML over HTTP. You make the HTTP request. You get an HTTP response. You deal with that response using whatever API your HTTP library provides. The only difference is that since you are using HTTPS the data will be encrypted on the other side of that API.

Comment: I already know the method that you described. I'm having trouble programatically implementing it. If you are familiar with QtWebkit then perhaps you can help me by showing an example code.